# C# XML Object Serialization: setting xmlns root attribute

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am serializing an object to xml and would like to set an xmlns attribute to the root node.

eg:

```
...
<root xmlns="[specified url]">
...
</root>
```

I cant seem to have an xmlns property/attribute on the member or seem to add the namespace when serializing without a prefix?

Any ideas?

Comment: I can do this by adding the namespace url to the constructor and then adding again when serializing, ommiting the prefix. Is this the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can do it as following. For top level use XmlRoot and for Properties use XmlElement

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(Namespace="http://topLevelNS")]
class MyClass
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Namespace = "http://SomeOtherNS")]
    public int MyVar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does add the namespace references but not in the way I need to support the XML format I am trying to duplicate.

Comment: Is there any solution to ignore the Namespace instead?

Comment: When `MyVar` is array this method is failed. We gets the first element without xmlns.